# Formula Fields in filter generating invalid sql from java

Tags: java, crystal-reports

I'm calling the Crystal Reports API from **java** to run a report.

In this report, i have a query filter that looks like this

```
{Employee.Type} <> "P" and
{Employee.HireDate} IN {?FromDate} TO {?ToDate} and
{@HAS_TAKEN_TIME_OFF}
```

where `@HAS_TAKEN_TIME_OFF` is a boolean returning Crystal Report *formula field*. This formula field performs a calculation against several other tables to figure out the boolean result of this.

The sql that gets generated looks like this

```
("Employee"."Type"<>'P' AND 
("Employee"."HireDate">=convert(datetime,'20110101 00:00:00.000') AND 
"Employee"."HireDate"<convert(datetime,'20120101 00:00:00.000')) 
AND ())
```

Clearly that trailing `AND ()` is invalid sql and does not represent the calculation that SHOULD be in its place, and since this is being executed from java, the sql is being created from the API, and sent to the db without the Crystal Reports interface.

within my java code, i certainly COULD perform my own replacement on this filter text by recursively replacing any function with the code from the function. I believe this is actually the job of the crystal reports API and i may simply be using this api incorrectly.

What is needed within the crystal reports java api to generate the correct sql from java such that functions are properly included? Do i really need to do this work for crystal reports?

Comment: this formula `{@HAS_TAKEN_TIME_OFF}` is returning null hence the error, check exactly what does formula contains and why returning null, I don't think API issue here

Comment: The formula seems to be valid. if i replace the formula placeholder with the contents of the formula, this works correctly. Again, the issue is with the sql created from java. if i use a profiler and watch the query generated during running this from Crystal Reports, the sql that is actually executed is correct.

Comment: Did you find any mis match between the sql statements from Java and profiler

Comment: yes. that's exactly how i diagnosed this problem. looking at the sql profiler, the sql is generated correctly when run through the CR UI. But when java triggers this report through the API, the sql generated is as i showed above in the post ( and() instead of actual code)